# Custom resolution not working

Tags: linux, xrandr, resolution, amd-graphics

I'm trying to add 1440x1080 @ 144hz to use with my 144hz BenQ monitor. Somehow, my monitor always gives me a black screen with an "Out of range" error when I load that resolution after adding it. Below is how I added, does anyone know what I might have missed? GPU is an AMD RX580 on Arch linux

```
[pstn@pstn ~]$ cvt 1440 1080 144
# 1440x1080 143.80 Hz (CVT) hsync: 169.25 kHz; pclk: 338.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x1080_144.00"  338.50  1440 1568 1720 2000  1080 1083 1087 1177 -hsync +vsync
[pstn@pstn ~]$ xrandr --newmode "1440x1080_144.00"  338.50  1440 1568 1720 2000  1080 1083 1087 1177 -hsync +vsync
[pstn@pstn ~]$ xrandr --addmode DVI-D-1 1440x1080_144.00
[pstn@pstn ~]$ xrandr --output DVI-D-1 --mode 1440x1080_144.00
```

thanks in advance